# how to list all directories and a specific line inside a file in that directory

Tags: command-line, server, scripts

My server has hosted many websites for testing/dev purposes. My problem is that my mysql server has around 95% load. So, I want to list all the directories and the db lines from config.php. Things like

```
like foo-dev : db@mysql01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `find` command to search your document root directory recursively for `config.php` files, then pass the results to the `grep` command to check for your search string e.g.

```
find /var/www -name 'config.php' -exec grep -l 'db@mysql01' {} \;
```

The `-l` flag to `grep` tells it to output the full name of the file (including the parent directory) instead of the actual matching text. You may need to modify the /var/www/ part if you are using non-standard file locations. NB I don't know if db@mysql01 is actually an appropriate search string - it may need to be something like db_name = xxx.

*Alternatively you might try examining your mysql and/or webserver logs, or using network tools like `lsof` to identify what processes have open connections to the mysql server.*

Comment: i understood the command. But what's the use of {} \; at the end?

Comment: `{}` is a placeholder for the list of files to be passed to `grep` and `;` just terminates the `exec` action - it needs to be escaped `\;` or quoted `';' to prevent interpretation by the shell.